# Remotely get serial number and model from list in batch script

Tags: list, batch-file, remote-access, wmic, serial-number

I am trying to create a simple script that will use computer name from pclist.txt and get serial number and model and export to csv file. I just can not seem to figure out why it does not print the serial number and model in the csv file. Here is my simple script.

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (pclist.txt) do (
     for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%M in ('wmic /node:%%i csproduct get name /value') do set "Model=%%M"
     for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic /node:%%i bios get serialnumber /value') do set "SN=%%I"
     echo %%i, %SN%, %Model% >> list.csv
     )
pause
```

Comment: The `>>` pipe pipes to existing files, does the file already exist before the running of this batch-file as I see you have to `>` in the file.

Comment: Yes it does exist.  It just outputs computer name from the pclist.txt

Comment: Does the batch file start in the same directory as the file or do you cd to the directory somewhere in the file?

Comment: Its all within the same directory.

Comment: But where does the batch-file *start in*. you can see this by turning echo on.

Comment: after turning echo on, it is starting from the directory where I have all the files.

Comment: when I turned echo on, I noticed that it would get the SN and the model but when they were called in the echo the values would not show just the variable

Comment: So do you know the error now? :P

Comment: It seems to be where the variables are set and how they are called correct? I feel it is hitting me in the face but trying to figure out where error is lol

Comment: Yes, correct, and also you might want to change the variables for the for loop since there are 2 `%%i`s but different cases. Might be confusing.

Comment: Maybe I am missing it, if I run echo on, I can see the variable is defined but when it is called in the echo, it looks to me like it is correct but does not... ahh lol

Comment: Can you add your echo on output to the question? :)

Comment: I appreciate all the help so far but I dont think I understand your question

Comment: Can you add what shows when you have echo on to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood what your intention was, but I would have expected the following to be the general way of achieving your intended task.

```batch-file
@%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe /Node:@pclist.txt /FailFast:1000 /Output:list.csv CSProduct Get Name /Format:CSV
@%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe /Node:@pclist.txt /FailFast:1000 /Append:list.csv BIOS Get SerialNumber /Format:CSV
@Pause
```

If you wanted to try to just output each item along side the node name separated by commas, then perhaps this will suffice:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
(
    For /F UseBackQDelims^=^ EOL^= %%G In (
        "pclist.txt"
    ) Do (
        For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%H In (
            '%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe /Node:%%G /FailFast:1000 CSProduct Get Name /Format:MOF'
        ) Do (
            For /F Tokens^=6Delims^=^" %%I In (
                '%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe /Node:%%G /FailFast:1000 BIOS Get SerialNumber /Format:MOF'
            ) Do Echo %%G,%%H,%%I
        )
    )
)>"list.csv"
Pause
```

Comment: That is close to what I am looking for, just one to get it all on one line and each value in its own colum

Comment: @stealthmode47, I've edited my answer to include a version with different formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would run fine - when `wmic` wouldn't have that ugly line ending of `CRCRLF`. The first `CR` becomes part of your variable. `CR` means "set the cursor back to the beginning of the line", so everything echoed after (in the same line) overwrites the previous content.

You can solve that with another `for` loop to strip the remaining `CR`. And you don't need the variables `SN` and `Model`; when you nest the `for` loops, you can use the `for` variables directly instead:

```
@echo off
del list.csv 2>nul
for /f %%i in (pclist.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%M in ('wmic /node:"%%i" csproduct get name /value') do for %%m in (%%M) do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%S in ('wmic /node:"%%i" bios get serialnumber /value') do for %%s in (%%S) do (
      >>list.csv echo %%i, %%s, %%m
    )
  )
)
type list.csv
pause
```

(Compo's code works, because the desired string is cut from the middle of a line, so the line ending doesn't matter)

Comment: Stephan, I've just noticed that you were blinded by the line endings issue, and as a result fell straight into the infamous delayed expansion trap!

Comment: @Compo: indeed... Didn't notice due to the lack of `setlocal`. Changed it to a version that doesn't need delayed expansion (I intended to do that anyway, but it was quite late yesterday)